# C# XML File: How to select a node with a certain value using LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq

I am having difficulties figuring out the **Linq** way to extract the value of the specific node.

Lets say my XML file is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <Month>
    <Month_Number>1</Month_Number>
    <Tool>
      <Tool_Name>Help</Tool_Name>
      <Count>1</Count>
    </Tool>
  </Month>
  <Month>
    <Month_Number>2</Month_Number>
    <Tool>
      <Tool_Name>On</Tool_Name>
      <Count>1</Count>
    </Tool>
  </Month>
  <Month>
    <Month_Number>3</Month_Number>
    <Tool>
      <Tool_Name>Off</Tool_Name>
      <Count>1</Count>
    </Tool>
  </Month>
</Data>
```

I would like to extract value from**Count** which is from **Tool** with **Tool_Name** with value of **Off** in **Month** where **Month_Number** is **3**.

The answer should be **1**. Then I would like to change that value to **2**

So resulting XML file would be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Data>
  <Month>
    <Month_Number>1</Month_Number>
    <Tool>
      <Tool_Name>Help</Tool_Name>
      <Count>1</Count>
    </Tool>
  </Month>
  <Month>
    <Month_Number>2</Month_Number>
    <Tool>
      <Tool_Name>On</Tool_Name>
      <Count>1</Count>
    </Tool>
  </Month>
  <Month>
    <Month_Number>3</Month_Number>
    <Tool>
      <Tool_Name>Off</Tool_Name>
      <Count>2</Count>
    </Tool>
  </Month>
</Data>
```

using **XMLDocument** I would do something similar to

```
XmlDocument tallyFile = new XmlDocument();
                    tallyFile.Load(tallyFilePath);

                    XmlNode node = tallyFile["Data"];
foreach (XmlNode childNode in node.ChildNodes)
{
if (childNode["Month_Number"].InnerText.Equals("3")){}
}
```

But I would like to achieve the above using **XDocument**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this code, just reference the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/linq/linq-xml-overview)

```cs
using System.Xml.Linq;

XElement root = XElement.Load(tallyFilePath);
foreach (var month in root.Descendants("Month")
    .Where(x => x.Descendants("Month_Number").First().Value == "3"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(month);
    //month.Value = "2";
}
```